# Quarto/Markdown PDF rendering problem (missing title, wrong font)

Tags: latex, markdown, quarto, xelatex

I got a problem when rendering a markdown document to pdf in VSC with the quarto extensions. A pdf document is created but it does not include the title and it does not use the specified font.

My .qmd file:

```
---
title: "Flood forecasting"
subtitle: "Termpaper 1 "
author: "Author"

bibliography: Termpaper1_literature.yaml

format: 
    pdf: 
      colorlinks: true
      mainfont: Tahoma
      sansfont: Tahoma
      monofont: Tahoma
---

## Abstract

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>. 

## Introduction

## Artificial Neural Networks

## Discussion

## References

::: {#refs}
:::
```

This is the output I get in the terminal:

```
➜  TERMPAPER1 Kopie git:(master) ✗ quarto preview "/Users/.../TERMPAPER1.qmd" -
-to pdf --no-browser --no-watch-inputs
pandoc 
  to: latex
  output-file: TERMPAPER1.tex
  standalone: true
  pdf-engine: xelatex
  variables:
    graphics: true
    tables: true
  default-image-extension: pdf
  
metadata
  documentclass: scrartcl
  classoption:
    - DIV=11
    - numbers=noendperiod
  papersize: letter
  header-includes:
    - '\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}'
  block-headings: true
  
running xelatex - 1
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
   restricted \write18 enabled.
  entering extended mode
  
running xelatex - 2
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
   restricted \write18 enabled.
  entering extended mode
  

Output created: TERMPAPER1.pdf
```

And the pdf looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for helping!

Changing the latex engine doesn't result in anything sadly.

Comment: Do you have Tahoma installed in your operating system? If I compile your example with lualatex instead of xelatex, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5JTb.png Can you show your .log file?

Comment: This is what I get in the renderer.log:

Comment: 2023-02-12 13:50:42.368 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'github.vscode-pull-request-github' wants API proposal 'commentsResolvedState' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-02-12 13:50:42.581 [info] Initial editor state {"filesToOpenOrCreate":[{"fileUri":{"$mid":1,"path":"/Users/~.qmd","scheme":"file"},"type":1,"exists":true,"options":{}}],"filesToDiff":[],"filesToMerge":[]}

Comment: 2023-02-12 13:51:00.934 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 68ms
2023-02-12 13:52:07.531 [error] [Extension Host] (node:10036) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Comment: To be precise: I'd like to see the latex .log file. It should start with something like "This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex 2023.2.8)  12 FEB 2023 15:02
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled." (In case your editor automatically throws away the log file, maybe you need to add `keep_tex: true` to your header and then manually run `xelatex whateever_your_filename_is` to get the logfile)

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the tipp. The strange thing is, that when I put the keep_tex in the preamble it doesnt do anything. Also when the pdf engine is set to lualatex it still compiles with xelatex...

Comment: Maybe try without all the empty lines in the yaml header?